# How can I throw an error if a parameter is null or 0?

Tags: sql-server

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_test_status]
    @CreatedBy      INT OUTPUT,
    @TestStatusId   INT OUTPUT,
    @UserTestId     INT,
    @UserId         INT
AS
```

How can I throw an error if the @UserId parameter is a null or zero ?

Here's what I tried but it gives a syntax error:

```
IF (@UserId = 0 OR @UserId IS NULL)
    THROW 70001, "UserId: Cannot be zero or null" , 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you've missed the **; -colon**

```
IF (@UserId = 0 OR @UserId IS NULL)
        THROW 70001, 'UserId: Cannot be zero or null' , 1;
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Express

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`RAISERROR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx):

```
IF @UserId = 0 OR @UserId IS NULL
  RAISERROR (N'This is message %s %d.', -- Message text.
             10, -- Severity,
             1, -- State,
             N'number', -- First argument.
             5); -- Second argument.
-- The message text returned is: This is message number 5.
```

Comment: What's the difference between that and THROW? Thanks

Comment: `THROW` was introduced with SQL Server 2012. For a thorough discussion on the diefferences between the two statements have a look [here](http://sqlhints.com/2013/06/30/differences-between-raiserror-and-throw-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  I did try what you suggested but with THROW and it is giving me an error.  Not sure if you have any idea what might be causing that.

Comment: `THROW` has a simpler syntax. What error do you get and what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am getting a syntax error SQL80001 in the VS2015 SQL editor window.